# SML Traverse an N-ary tree

Tags: tree, sml

I'm a newbie to SML.

After a couple of searches, I still can't find any resource related to traversing an n-ary tree. Many examples are just traversing a simple binary tree.

Say, I have

```
datatype 'a tree = leaf of 'a list | node of 'a tree list
```

I want to traverse this n-ary tree and have the exactly same tree returned (`val traverse = fn : 'a tree -> 'a tree`)

How can I do?

Here's my code:

```
fun traverse (leaf x) = (leaf x)
  | traverse (node []) = node []
  | traverse (node [x]) = node [x]
```

I'm struggling to add the last pattern, i.e., (this is wrong)

```
  | traverse (node (x::xs)) = traverse (node x) :: traverse (xs)
```

Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `traverse` is a function from trees to trees, you can traverse all the subtrees in the list with `map` (and you don't need special cases):

```
fun traverse (leaf x) = leaf x
  | traverse (node xs) = node (map traverse xs)
```